# HTML & Bootstrap dropdown select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I fix this design? I am using Bootstrap 3.

Code:

```
<b>Course:</b>
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="course" class="form-control">
        ...php code...
    </select>
    <select name="yearlevel" class="form-control">
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
    </select>
    <select name="section" class="form-control">
        <option>L</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>G</option>
        <option>U</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Picture:

[image]

I want the 3 dropdown boxes to be on the same line. 
How would I fix this design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to wrap the `<select>` tags in a `.form-inline` class; that'll render any `.form-control` elements inside it to display using `inline-block` instead of `block` so that they'll all sit on a single line instead of pushing each other to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this html

```
<b>Course:</b>
<div id="lineblock" class="form-group">
    <select name="course" class="form-control">
        ...php code...
    </select>
    <select name="yearlevel" class="form-control">
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
    </select>
    <select name="section" class="form-control">
        <option>L</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>G</option>
        <option>U</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and the following css

```
#lineblock select{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

You can see live working demo of it here
http://jsfiddle.net/rgf1kvkv/

Comment: Just something I noticed about your solution: you're floating the elements but not applying a clearfix to keep them inside the container. Unless `form-group` applies one I'm forgetting about?